# Checkinstall fail installing gnu gcc 6.2.0

Tags: linux, debian, gcc

I try to install from source GCC 6.2.0 with checkinstall but it fails.

I run configure and make, all seems fine, but when I try checkinstall I have this error:

```
ranlib: could not create temporary file whilst writing archive: No more archived files
```

Log when it occurs:

```
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/alexandre/Documents/objdir/libcc1'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/alexandre/Documents/objdir/libcc1'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alexandre/Documents/objdir/libcc1'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/alexandre/Documents/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc'
/bin/bash /home/alexandre/Documents/objdir/../gcc-6.2.0/libgcc/../mkinstalldirs /home/alexandre/gcc-6.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libgcc_eh.a /home/alexandre/gcc-6.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/
chmod 644 /home/alexandre/gcc-6.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/libgcc_eh.a
ranlib /home/alexandre/gcc-6.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/libgcc_eh.a
ranlib: could not create temporary file whilst writing archive: No more archived files
Makefile:1112: recipe for target 'install-shared' failed
make[2]: *** [install-shared] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/alexandre/Documents/objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc'
Makefile:17621: recipe for target 'install-target-libgcc' failed
make[1]: *** [install-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/alexandre/Documents/objdir'
Makefile:2323: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. Sometimes checkinstall breaks an installation because of missing folder. It also (for some bug) refuses to create a new folder though it has necessary permission to create that. All you need to do in this case is to create the folder manually. In this case create the folder **`/home/alexandre/gcc-6.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0`** and set permission manually.

> sudo mkdir /home/alexandre/gcc-6.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0
>
> sudo chmod 644 /home/alexandre/gcc-6.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.0

Another possibility is that you may have missed the configuration step before installing it. Please try configuring  with

> ./configure --disable-static

, recompiling it and installing it with checkinstall.

Comment: Now its makedir not working... `code`mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/alexandre/gcc-6.2.0/libexec/': No such file or directory`code` I reconfigure, remake and sudo mkdir / chmod.

Comment: Possibly there is no such folder called `gcc-6.2.0` in `/home/alexandre` directory. You need to start creating folder from `/home/alexandre` and all the rest of the folders in next subsequent steps.

Comment: This is what I did, the problem occurs when I run checkinstall.